# check user account ad_SSmith does not have dbo on multiple database (SQL server 2008 R2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have about 100+ databases, and I want to check which database user `ad_SSMith` does not have `dbo` in. I ran `EXEC sp_MSforeachdb` to check which database he HAS `dbo`, but I would like to see which one he does not rather then doing a check off list and going back.

Is there away I can check all the databases to see in which ones the user does not have `dbo`?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
declare @sql varchar(281);
set @sql = 'use [?]; 
if exists (select 1 from sys.database_principals p
inner join sys.database_role_members r on p.principal_id = r.member_principal_id
where p.Name = ''domain\ad_SSMith''
and r.role_principal_id = 16384)
select DB_NAME(), ''db_owner''
else
select DB_NAME(), ''Not db_owner'''

exec sp_msforeachdb @sql;
```